# Python/Django Comparing two float values leads to TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, string-comparison

I'm experiencing the following strange behavior when I run my functional tests with Selenium.

I have a JavaScript program that populates an input field within Selenium. I check for the correct values in that input field (see below). The test runs as a class of `StaticLiveServerTestCase`.

```
    # Values to compare against
    lng= 8.63259210000001

    # Get the value attribute of the field
    lng_field = float(self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_lng').get_attribute('value'))

    # if i use pdb.set_trace() at this position i can do 
    # all the following operations without any problems

    # When i do any of the following i get an error message
    mydiff = abs(lng_field-lng)
    # or
    lng_field==lng
```

For any other operation where there is a comparison or computation involving `lng` and `lng_field`, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "...", line XXX, in mytest
>       mydiff = abs(lng_field-lng)
>   TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

However, everything works within the console when I use `pdb.set_trace()`(every operation works perfectly fine).

Even when I convert both values to strings and only use the first 5 characters (`mystring[:5]`) within the string the code line with the comparison leads to the error stated above.

The comparison is not even failing, there is just no comparison during runtime, but everything works fine in the console.

I also tried using `copy.deepcopy()` of the values before I compare them, but still I get the same error when I run the functional tests.

- **Python Version:** 3.4.5
- **Django:** 1.10.5
- **IDE:** PyDev
- **OS:** Windows 10

Any ideas?